# Load information from database to uiwebview as html

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiwebview, load

I want to load my information that I took from database to the UIWebView as a Html.I dont know how to approach this problem.Can you help me ..How can I do that??Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[webview loadHTMLString:[self stringByDecodingXMLEntities:[TBXML textForElement:comment]] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

Hi everyone ,
thank you for ur answers,ur interest.I have my solution now.I need to add this part and also I need to decode my html..Nothing more..I hope helpfull

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you have only a database and want to present this data to the UIWebView.

[UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview)

> You use the UIWebView class to embed web content in your application.
>   To do so, you simply create a UIWebView object, attach it to a window,
>   and send it a request to load web content. You can also use this class
>   to move back and forward in the history of webpages, and you can even
>   set some web content properties programmatically.

You need to develop your site and load content from it.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;

   //Create a URL object.
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

   //URL Requst Object
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   //Load the request in the UIWebView.
   [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: No ,I think I couldnt explain well..I dont mean this one..I mean Im using webservice and by connection I can access this information from my webservice ..(I can see this information in output) but I need to show user in webview..Or I dont know if is there any other tool in xcode??? I hope more clear?

Comment: if you have data, then you can do as Atulkumar V. Jain said. Make a html-string and load WebView by using "loadHTMLString".

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following link :-

[Creating a WebView programmatically and displaying NSStrings inside the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051003/creating-a-webview-programmatically-and-displaying-nsstrings-inside-the-view/4051782#4051782)

Hope this might help you.............

Comment: If you are getting data from webservice then why do u want to show the result in web-view. The controls which u can use depends upon the response from server & ur requirements.